# Samba and usbmount: can't write on automounted device

Tags: debian, networking, samba, raspberry-pi, automounting

This is my problem:

I configured my RPi with Debian:

- Samba shares `/media/`, that is readable-writeable-executable from my home network
- `usbmount` automount USB devices when inserted in my RPi, in `/media/usb`
- No users should be logged in, to do this

When I insert an USB device, usbmount mount it correctly, so RPi can write on it and I can READ it through network.
BUT no one are allowed to WRITE on it through network.

Checking permissions on `/media/usb` I found that:

- BEFORE usbmount mount device `/media/usb` is `rwx-rwx-rwx`
- AFTER usbmount mount device `/media/usb` became `rwx-r-r`, so only `root` (usbmount work mounting devices as root) can write on it

So I've tryed to change the `FS_MOUNTPOINTS=""` line in `/etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf` file but I don't know how to force usbmount to automount devices `rwx-rwx-rwx` or with "low-user write permission".

I've also tryed to change `MOUNTOPTIONS` line. But I don't know what add to solve the problem. My `MOUNTOPTIONS` line:

```
MOUNTOPTIONS="sync,noexec,nodev,noatime,nodiratime"
```

This question is also [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29688/samba-and-usbmount-cant-write-on-automounted-device), but no one replied to me.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

try the mount options: `gid=ownerGroupID,uid=ownerID`

Comment: What do you mean with 'ownerGroupID' and with 'ownerID'? I would access remotely, without login in the RPi, so I haven't any group or user ID

Comment: the ids of the linux user that should have access to the files

Comment: There isn't any linux user...  I want it will be readable-writeable-executable through network, so i should access it with a Windows pc